# How can i remove 5 minutes from current date() in PHP

Tags: php, date

I would like to show me the date minus 5 minutes from the current time;
my code is like this:

```
(date('Y-m-d H:i-5:s'))
```

but it's not correct because `var_dump` produces:

**2012-08-08 13:27-5:49**

Any ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**PHP Function:**

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

**Example:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 minutes'));
```

Comment: Trying to *teach* you to fish. Although, looks like @salathe *gave* you the fish :)

Comment: cool man, it works, thanks for both of you ! i will accept it in 10 mins :)

Comment: You seemed happy enough to be fishmonger by handing the answer to Jimmy on a plate; I just used the same date format as the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this It's solve your problem

```
$format = "h:i A";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date($format, strtotime("-5 minute"));
```