# How to minus 5 minutes from System Date in PHP?

Tags: php, yii

Consider the following,

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$sysdate = date_format($date, 'H:i:s');
echo $sysdate;

Result:  17:31:48
```

Let me know how to minus 5 minutes from sysdate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In objective style, you can use method sub and DateInterval object:

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

echo  $date->format('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT5M'));
echo  $date->format('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
```

result:

```
17:44:04
17:39:04
```

Answer (score 6):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870001/how-can-i-remove-5-minutes-from-current-date-in-php)

**PHP Function:**

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

**Example:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 minutes'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this! hope this may help...

> $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
>
> $sysdate = date_format(strtotime($date), 'H:i:s');
>
> echo date('H:i:s',time($sysdate) - 05*60);

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this might help..`$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT0H5M'));`

Link::

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php
```

Answer (score 1):

> $date = strtotime("-5 minutes")